# C# Datagrid send rows depends on cell value in HTML

Tags: c#, datagrid, outlook

I have a little problem with Datagrid.

Datagrid taken from SQL ->

[image: MyDataGrid]

Main points are:

- 1st column with number,

- last column (8th) with email.

I'd like to send in HTML Body via Outlook (table in body) with list of data from rows, where 1st column (number) is the same, for email which is stored on 8th. In loop to send groupped info to each number.

Now i'm using separatelly row per email, but i need to config with group per value from 1st column (list of rows). Below my sample:

```
con.Open();
String query = "xxxxxxxx";
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SDA.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
con.Close();
for (int i = 0; i < DataGridView.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    1 = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
    2 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
    3 = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
    4 = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
    5 = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value).ToString("N");
    6 = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value).ToString("N");
    7 = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value).ToString("N");
    Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
    mailItem.Subject = "xxx" + 1 + "xxx" + 2 + "xxx";
    mailItem.To = "xxxx@xxxxx";
    mailItem.HTMLBody = "aaaaaaaaa" + 1 + "bb: " + 2 + "vvvv."
    mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
    mailItem.Display(false);
    ((Outlook._MailItem)mailItem).Send();
}
```

I tried already with:

```
string mailBody = "<table width='100%' style='border:Solid 1px Black;'>";
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    mailBody += "<tr>";
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        mailBody += "<td style='color:blue;'>" + cell.Value + "</td>";
    }
    mailBody += "</tr>";
}
mailBody += "</table>";
mailItem.HTMLBody = mailBody;
```

But in this style, I got full DataGrid into an email.

Can you help me how to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't fully clear what you are trying to achieve, what you are currently experiencing, or what you have tried, because the supplied code is fragmented and incomplete.

Comment: In short way - i got datagrid. I'd like to send informations which are in rows to definded emails. Content of email should have rows from datagrid, but "groupped" via 1st column. So for number 1000130 we send all rows where 1000130 exist, in one email. Email is stored on 8th column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
DataTable dt = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
//assuming your first columns name is 1...
var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x["1"]);

foreach (var group in groups)
{
   // create your mailItem instance....

   string mailBody = "<table width='100%' style='border:Solid 1px Black;'>";

   List<string> mailsToSend = new List<string>();

   foreach (var row in group)
   {
       mailBody += "<tr>";

       mailItem.Recipients.add(row.ItemArray[7].toString());

       foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray)
       {
          mailBody += "<td style='color:blue;'>" + cell.ToString() + "</td>";

       }
       mailBody += "</tr>";
   }

   mailBody += "</table>";
   mailItem.HTMLBody = mailBody;

   //Send your mail....
}
```

**Update**

You can create a mail list which has unique mails...

```
foreach (var group in groups)
{
     // create your mailItem instance....


     List<string> mailsToSend = new List<string>();

     string mailBody = "<table width='100%' style='border:Solid 1px Black;'>";

      foreach (var row in group)
      {
          mailBody += "<tr>";

          // if not in the list, simply add...
          if (!mailsToSend.Contains(row.ItemArray[7].ToString()))
          {
             mailsToSend.Add(row.ItemArray[7].ToString());
          }

          foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray)
          {
             mailBody += "<td style='color:blue;'>" + cell.ToString() + "</td>";
          }
          mailBody += "</tr>";
     }

     //fill your recipients from your mail list...
     foreach (var mail in mailsToSend)
     {
        mailItem.Recipients.Add(mail);
     }

     mailBody += "</table>";
     mailItem.HTMLBody = mailBody;

     //Send your mail....
}
```

**Update**

Just take 7 cells...

```
foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray.Take(7))
{
    mailBody += "<td style='color:blue;'>" + cell.ToString() + "</td>";
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly ! Question - if i have in one group 10 rows, and all inside group have always the same email inside 8th column, to not send 10 times the same message to the same email - i can move this mailItem before one foreach and should work ? Or something more ?

Comment: It’s very helpfull and improve my skills and software. Last question - last column is email, but i’d like to don’t send email address in body of email, because make no sense. Can i only make like „array - 1” or simmilar ? To better understand, i’d like to take whole row, like is, but without last column in body, but i need this column for sending email (to take email address).

Comment: hi @Tom, glad to help :).I've updated my answer for your last question...

Comment: Everything works perfectly ! One last help in this topic - how to send summary of sent emails in one email, to defined email address. In short words - make and send summary what script did.

Comment: What exactly does the summary contains? Define your summary @Tom, maybe an example...

Comment: Sometimes i have to read something 10 times to have an idea :) summary i created it in easy way - take whole info from selected datagridview - easiest way and simple. Thanks one more time.